# C++ String replace

Tags: string, replace, c++17

How can we replace a substring in C++ using str.replace?

Eg: str = "DOLLARISLLOD"

str.replace("LL","00")
str = "DO00ARIS00OD"

In c++, it asks for index to begin and end, but if I want to generalize the replacement as and when those substrings occur.

Comment: Sounds like you might want to use https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_replace